# Hadoop MapReduce Atomic Split

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, cloud, hdfs

I want to explain my problem: I want to process a group of images `in`.jpg` format. Let's assume the size of images is 1 GB. I'd like to do that on the map reduce framework to improve the elaboration.

My idea is to split the 1 GB of images in 64 MB groups (so it would be at most 16 groups of images). Because it's the same as the size of an HDFS chunk and can reduce the overhead of transferring chunks.

I don't understand how to split the images in an atomic way. I know that I should implement the `FileInputFormat` class and the method `getSplit()`. But I would like help in doing that.